# Предложение с деепричастными оборотами

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли расставлены запятые?

**Устав от нашего пыльного и скучного родного города, я воображала, как, возможно, посчастливится прокатиться на верблюде или походить там, где, управляя персонажем, бегала в игре.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [посчастли́виться](https://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&all=x), -вится; ***св. безл.*** (кому), с инф.
   Об удачном, благоприятном для кого-либо стечении обстоятельств.
   *Ему посчастливилось встречаться с известным поэтом. Туристам посчастливилось: погода прекрасная! Посчастливилось познакомиться с кем-либо.*

В вашем предложении (без контекста) возникает "непонятность": **кому именно** посчастливится прокатиться и походить. Поэтому, думаю, надо добавить местоимение "мне".

2. А с пунктуацией все в порядке — запятые на месте.

**Устав от нашего пыльного и скучного родного города,**(1) **я воображала,**(2) **как мне,**(3) **возможно,**(4) **посчастливится прокатиться на верблюде или походить там,**(5) **где,**(6) **управляя персонажем,**(7) **бегала в игре.**
(1) — закрывает деепричастный оборот;
(2) — ставится перед придаточным предложением [как];
(3) и (4) — выделяют вводное слово;
(5) — ставится перед придаточным предложением [где];
(6) и (7) — обособляют деепричастный оборот.

Comment: Римма, а "бегала в игре" - это нормально? Может быть, "участвовала в игре" или что-то в этом роде?

Comment: Я не знаток компьютерных игр, но мне кажется, что @Kate "сплавляет" себя с тем персонажем, которым управляла. В этой игре она бегала , а в другой могла бы прыгать, летать или плавать.

Comment: @Sharon После следующей игры она, возможно, вообразит, как ей посчастливится посидеть на облаке, вокруг которого, управляя персонажем, кружила в игре. Мне думается, что ТАК (в этом контексте) можно говорить.

Comment: Спасибо большое :)

Comment: @Римма Михайлова  Вот эта история. https://tbooklist.org/books/3360/read  Всё-таки я считаю, что хотя бы кавычки поставить нужно, чтобы было видно, что слово употреблено в необычном (авторском) значении. Сочетания "бегать в игре" в русском языке нет. Без специального обозначения оно выглядит как грамматическая погрешность.